# Can I list the files and directories on a logical volume

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

I have a logical volume, `/dev/dm-0` that is 95% full. I want to delete some directories and files from it to free up space.

How can I access the content of this logical volume?

Comment: A volume is like a partition - AFAIK it will need to be *mounted* in order to perform file operations.

Comment: I understand the volume is spread across physical volumes, but since data is written on the volume, there must be way to list the files on it and manipulate those files and directories (edit files, delete files, directories, etc).

Comment: My bad.  Forget my last comment.  Long day here.  See https://superuser.com/questions/1052403/100-usage-dev-dm-1 as that might help.  If you run the `df` command it will show you the mount where it is.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance. I ran `df -h`, and it shows where it is mounted. But when I run `ls -la` in that directory, it only shows the files and subdirs in the dir, not this mounted volume. The volume has over 100GB on it, none of the files or subdirs in the mount point dir are over 300KB.

Comment: Oh, in that link the `ncdu` application is awesome to show where space is being used.